# Chained QSortFilterProxyModels

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside, qsortfilterproxymodel

Let's say I have a list variable `datalist` storing 10,000 string entities.
The `QTableView` needs to display only some of these entities. That's is why `QTableView` was assigned `QSortFilterProxyModel` that does all the filtering. 
After all Proxy work is completed the `QTableView` "receives" 25 entities to display (so remaining 9,975 entities were "filtered out".

Now, I create a `QLineEdit` to be used as a search field where the user can type a keyword to narrow down the list of the displayed 25 entities (items) even further. For this purpose I link `QLineEdit`'s `textChanged` signal to assigned to QTableView Proxy's `filterAcceptsRow()` method.

The problem I see here is that Proxy model needs to get back to the original 10,000 entities long list to re-filter once again. And again. And again.

I wonder if it is possible to create a second Proxy that would pickup what the first Proxy has already filtered out: 25 entities instead of 10,000.

So the resulting schema would look like this:

`datalist` > `QAbstractTableModel` > `QSortFilterProxyModel` > `QSortFilterProxyModel` > `QTableView`

Where:

`datalist` is 10,000 entities long list variable.

`QAbstractTableModel` is a base data model

`QSortFilterProxyModel` is a first Proxy Model doing the dirtiest and slowest filtering job

`QSortFilterProxyModel` is a second Proxy Model working on a pre-filtered by first Proxy data (it is used to filter by the user's keyword).

`QTableView` is a QTableView itself used to display the entity items.

So, the question is: is it a valid idea?

Comment: Naively, since `QSortFilterProxyModel.setSourceModel(model)` expects the model passed in to be subclass of `QAbstractItemModel` and `QSortFilterProxyModel` **is** a subclass of `QAbstractItemModel`, your idea should at least run without errors. Whether you get the speed-up you are looking for, I'm not sure. Definitely worth putting together a minimal test example and trying it though!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code below uses two ProxyModels filtering 10,000 items. It works... 
[image]

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
import sys

class MyTableModel(QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, *args):
        QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self, parent, *args)
        self.items = [i for i in range(10000)]

    def rowCount(self, parent):
        return len(self.items)       
    def columnCount(self, parent):
        return 1

    def data(self, index, role):
        if not index.isValid():
            return QVariant()
        elif role != Qt.DisplayRole:
            return QVariant()

        row=index.row()
        column=index.column()
        if row<len(self.items):
            return QVariant(self.items[row])
        else:
            return QVariant()

class Proxy01(QSortFilterProxyModel):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Proxy01, self).__init__()
    def filterAcceptsRow(self, row, parent):        
        sourceModel=self.sourceModel()
        index=sourceModel.index(row, 0, parent)
        name=sourceModel.data(index, Qt.DisplayRole).toString()

        if name and not int(name)%10:
            return True
        return False

class Proxy02(QSortFilterProxyModel):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Proxy02, self).__init__()
        self.keyword=None

    def setKeyword(self, arg):
        if arg: self.keyword=str(arg)
        self.reset()    

    def filterAcceptsRow(self, row, parent):
        sourceModel=self.sourceModel().sourceModel()
        index=sourceModel.index(row, 0, parent)
        name=sourceModel.data(index, Qt.DisplayRole).toString()

        if self.keyword and name and not self.keyword.lower() in str(name).lower():
            return False        
        return True

class MyWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        QWidget.__init__(self, *args)

        self.tablemodel=MyTableModel(self)               

        self.proxy1=Proxy01()
        self.proxy1.setSourceModel(self.tablemodel)

        self.proxy2=Proxy02()
        self.proxy2.setSourceModel(self.proxy1)

        tableviewA=QTableView() 
        tableviewA.setModel(self.proxy2)

        searchEdit=QLineEdit()
        searchEdit.textChanged.connect(self.proxy2.setKeyword)

        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(tableviewA)
        layout.addWidget(searchEdit)
        self.setLayout(layout)

    def test(self, arg):
        print arg

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Here is a single Proxy approach. Searching by keyword is noticably slower vs two proxys implementation:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
import sys

class MyTableModel(QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, *args):
        QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self, parent, *args)
        self.items = [i for i in range(10000)]

    def rowCount(self, parent):
        return len(self.items)       
    def columnCount(self, parent):
        return 1

    def data(self, index, role):
        if not index.isValid():
            return QVariant()
        elif role != Qt.DisplayRole:
            return QVariant()

        row=index.row()
        column=index.column()
        if row<len(self.items):
            return QVariant(self.items[row])
        else:
            return QVariant()

class Proxy01(QSortFilterProxyModel):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Proxy01, self).__init__()
        self.keyword=None

    def setKeyword(self, arg):
        if arg: self.keyword=str(arg)
        self.reset()    

    def filterAcceptsRow(self, row, parent):
        sourceModel=self.sourceModel()
        index=sourceModel.index(row, 0, parent)
        name=sourceModel.data(index, Qt.DisplayRole).toString()

        if self.keyword and name and not self.keyword.lower() in str(name).lower():
            return False        
        return True

class MyWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        QWidget.__init__(self, *args)

        self.tablemodel=MyTableModel(self)               

        self.proxy1=Proxy01()
        self.proxy1.setSourceModel(self.tablemodel)

        tableviewA=QTableView() 
        tableviewA.setModel(self.proxy1)

        searchEdit=QLineEdit()
        searchEdit.textChanged.connect(self.proxy1.setKeyword)

        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(tableviewA)
        layout.addWidget(searchEdit)
        self.setLayout(layout)

    def test(self, arg):
        print arg

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```