# Avoid redundant calls to QSortFilterProxyModel::filterAcceptsRow() if the filter has become strictly narrower

Tags: c++, qt, qsortfilterproxymodel

Is there any way invalidate the filter in a QSortFilterProxyModel, but to indicate that the filter has been narrowed down so `filterAcceptsRow()` should be called only on the currently visible rows?

Currently Qt doesn't do that. When I call `QSortFilterProxyModel::invalidateFilter()`, and my filter is changed from "abcd" to "abcde", an entirely new mapping is created, and `filterAcceptsRow()` is called on all source rows, even though it's obvious that source rows that were hidden so far will remain hidden.

This is the code from Qt's sources in `QSortFilterProxyModelPrivate::create_mapping()` which calls my overridden `filterAcceptsRow()`, and it creates an entirely new `Mapping` and iterates over all the source rows:

```
Mapping *m = new Mapping;

int source_rows = model->rowCount(source_parent);
m->source_rows.reserve(source_rows);
for (int i = 0; i < source_rows; ++i) {
    if (q->filterAcceptsRow(i, source_parent))
        m->source_rows.append(i);
}
```

What I want is to iterate only the visible rows in mapping and call `filterAcceptsRow()` only on them. If a row is already hidden `filterAcceptsRow()` should not be called on it, because we already know that it would return false for it (the filter has become more stringent, it hasn't been loosened).

Since I have overriden `filterAcceptsRow()`, Qt can't know the nature of the filter, but when I call `QSortFilterProxyModel::invalidateFilter()`, I have the information about whether the filter has become strictly narrower, so I could pass that information to Qt if it has a way of accepting it.

On the other hand, if I've changed the filter from `abcd` to `abce`, then the filter should be called on all source rows, since it has become strictly narrower.

Comment: `filterAcceptsRow( )` is virtual so you could reimplement it and call `QSortFilterProxyModel::invalidateFilter()`

Comment: @deW1 Thanks, but I'm not sure this addresses what I'm asking. I've updated my question to make it more clear what I'm after.

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27975594/chained-qsortfilterproxymodels) question suggests *chaining `QSortFilterProxyModel`s*. But I think there should be better approaches into this problem.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb there is no reason to patch it, if you can specify the behavior by deriving (you also can get into licensing issues)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I wrote a [`QIdentityProxyModel`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qidentityproxymodel.html) subclass that stores a list of chained `QSortFilterProxyModel`. It provides an interface similar to `QSortFilterProxyModel` and accepts a `narrowedDown` boolean parameter that indicates if the filter is being narrowed down. So that:

- When the filter is being narrowed down, a new `QSortFilterProxyModel` is appended to the chain, and the `QIdentityProxyModel` switches to proxy the new filter at the end of the chain.
- Otherwise, It deletes all the filters in the chain, constructs a new chain with one filter that corresponds to the current filtering criteria. After that, the `QIdentityProxyModel` switches to proxy the new filter in the chain.

Here is a program that compares the class to using a normal `QSortFilterProxyModel` subclass:

[image: Demo program screenshot]

```
#include <QtWidgets>

class FilterProxyModel : public QSortFilterProxyModel{
public:
    explicit FilterProxyModel(QObject* parent= nullptr):QSortFilterProxyModel(parent){}
    ~FilterProxyModel(){}

    //you can override filterAcceptsRow here if you want
};

//the class stores a list of chained FilterProxyModel and proxies the filter model

class NarrowableFilterProxyModel : public QIdentityProxyModel{
    Q_OBJECT
    //filtering properties of QSortFilterProxyModel
    Q_PROPERTY(QRegExp filterRegExp READ filterRegExp WRITE setFilterRegExp)
    Q_PROPERTY(int filterKeyColumn READ filterKeyColumn WRITE setFilterKeyColumn)
    Q_PROPERTY(Qt::CaseSensitivity filterCaseSensitivity READ filterCaseSensitivity WRITE setFilterCaseSensitivity)
    Q_PROPERTY(int filterRole READ filterRole WRITE setFilterRole)
public:
    explicit NarrowableFilterProxyModel(QObject* parent= nullptr):QIdentityProxyModel(parent), m_filterKeyColumn(0),
        m_filterCaseSensitivity(Qt::CaseSensitive), m_filterRole(Qt::DisplayRole), m_source(nullptr){
    }

    void setSourceModel(QAbstractItemModel* sourceModel){
        m_source= sourceModel;
        QIdentityProxyModel::setSourceModel(sourceModel);
        for(FilterProxyModel* proxyNode : m_filterProxyChain) delete proxyNode;
        m_filterProxyChain.clear();
        applyCurrentFilter();
    }

    QRegExp filterRegExp()const{return m_filterRegExp;}
    int filterKeyColumn()const{return m_filterKeyColumn;}
    Qt::CaseSensitivity filterCaseSensitivity()const{return m_filterCaseSensitivity;}
    int filterRole()const{return m_filterRole;}

    void setFilterKeyColumn(int filterKeyColumn, bool narrowedDown= false){
        m_filterKeyColumn= filterKeyColumn;
        applyCurrentFilter(narrowedDown);
    }
    void setFilterCaseSensitivity(Qt::CaseSensitivity filterCaseSensitivity, bool narrowedDown= false){
        m_filterCaseSensitivity= filterCaseSensitivity;
        applyCurrentFilter(narrowedDown);
    }
    void setFilterRole(int filterRole, bool narrowedDown= false){
        m_filterRole= filterRole;
        applyCurrentFilter(narrowedDown);
    }
    void setFilterRegExp(const QRegExp& filterRegExp, bool narrowedDown= false){
        m_filterRegExp= filterRegExp;
        applyCurrentFilter(narrowedDown);
    }
    void setFilterRegExp(const QString& filterRegExp, bool narrowedDown= false){
        m_filterRegExp.setPatternSyntax(QRegExp::RegExp);
        m_filterRegExp.setPattern(filterRegExp);
        applyCurrentFilter(narrowedDown);
    }
    void setFilterWildcard(const QString &pattern, bool narrowedDown= false){
        m_filterRegExp.setPatternSyntax(QRegExp::Wildcard);
        m_filterRegExp.setPattern(pattern);
        applyCurrentFilter(narrowedDown);
    }
    void setFilterFixedString(const QString &pattern, bool narrowedDown= false){
        m_filterRegExp.setPatternSyntax(QRegExp::FixedString);
        m_filterRegExp.setPattern(pattern);
        applyCurrentFilter(narrowedDown);
    }

private:
    void applyCurrentFilter(bool narrowDown= false){
        if(!m_source) return;
        if(narrowDown){ //if the filter is being narrowed down
            //instantiate a new filter proxy model and add it to the end of the chain
            QAbstractItemModel* proxyNodeSource= m_filterProxyChain.empty()?
                        m_source : m_filterProxyChain.last();
            FilterProxyModel* proxyNode= newProxyNode();
            proxyNode->setSourceModel(proxyNodeSource);
            QIdentityProxyModel::setSourceModel(proxyNode);
            m_filterProxyChain.append(proxyNode);
        } else { //otherwise
            //delete all filters from the current chain
            //and construct a new chain with the new filter in it
            FilterProxyModel* proxyNode= newProxyNode();
            proxyNode->setSourceModel(m_source);
            QIdentityProxyModel::setSourceModel(proxyNode);
            for(FilterProxyModel* node : m_filterProxyChain) delete node;
            m_filterProxyChain.clear();
            m_filterProxyChain.append(proxyNode);
        }
    }
    FilterProxyModel* newProxyNode(){
        //return a new child FilterModel with the current properties
        FilterProxyModel* proxyNode= new FilterProxyModel(this);
        proxyNode->setFilterRegExp(filterRegExp());
        proxyNode->setFilterKeyColumn(filterKeyColumn());
        proxyNode->setFilterCaseSensitivity(filterCaseSensitivity());
        proxyNode->setFilterRole(filterRole());
        return proxyNode;
    }
    //filtering parameters for QSortFilterProxyModel
    QRegExp m_filterRegExp;
    int m_filterKeyColumn;
    Qt::CaseSensitivity m_filterCaseSensitivity;
    int m_filterRole;

    QAbstractItemModel* m_source;
    QList<FilterProxyModel*> m_filterProxyChain;
};

//Demo program that uses the class

//used to fill the table with dummy data
std::string nextString(std::string str){
    int length= str.length();
    for(int i=length-1; i>=0; i--){
        if(str[i] < 'z'){
            str[i]++; return str;
        } else str[i]= 'a';
    }
    return std::string();
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    //set up GUI
    QWidget w;
    QGridLayout layout(&w);
    QLineEdit lineEditFilter;
    lineEditFilter.setPlaceholderText("filter");
    QLabel titleTable1("NarrowableFilterProxyModel:");
    QTableView tableView1;
    QLabel labelTable1;
    QLabel titleTable2("FilterProxyModel:");
    QTableView tableView2;
    QLabel labelTable2;
    layout.addWidget(&lineEditFilter,0,0,1,2);
    layout.addWidget(&titleTable1,1,0);
    layout.addWidget(&tableView1,2,0);
    layout.addWidget(&labelTable1,3,0);
    layout.addWidget(&titleTable2,1,1);
    layout.addWidget(&tableView2,2,1);
    layout.addWidget(&labelTable2,3,1);

    //set up models
    QStandardItemModel sourceModel;
    NarrowableFilterProxyModel filterModel1;;
    tableView1.setModel(&filterModel1);

    FilterProxyModel filterModel2;
    tableView2.setModel(&filterModel2);

    QObject::connect(&lineEditFilter, &QLineEdit::textChanged, [&](QString newFilter){
        QTime stopWatch;
        newFilter.prepend("^"); //match from the beginning of the name
        bool narrowedDown= newFilter.startsWith(filterModel1.filterRegExp().pattern());
        stopWatch.start();
        filterModel1.setFilterRegExp(newFilter, narrowedDown);
        labelTable1.setText(QString("took: %1 msecs").arg(stopWatch.elapsed()));
        stopWatch.start();
        filterModel2.setFilterRegExp(newFilter);
        labelTable2.setText(QString("took: %1 msecs").arg(stopWatch.elapsed()));
    });

    //fill model with strings from "aaa" to "zzz" (17576 rows)
    std::string str("aaa");
    while(!str.empty()){
        QList<QStandardItem*> row;
        row.append(new QStandardItem(QString::fromStdString(str)));
        sourceModel.appendRow(row);
        str= nextString(str);
    }
    filterModel1.setSourceModel(&sourceModel);
    filterModel2.setSourceModel(&sourceModel);

    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

#### Notes:

- The class provides some kind of optimization only when the filter is being *narrowed down*, since the newly constructed filter at the end of the chain does not need to search through all source model's rows.
- The class depends on the user to tell if the filter is being *narrowed down*. That is when the user passes `true` for the argument `narrowedDown`, the filter is assumed to be a special case of the current filter (even if it is not really so). Otherwise, it behaves exactly the same as the normal `QSortFilterProxyModel` and possibly with some additional overhead (resulted from cleaning up the old filter chain).
- The class can be further optimized when the filter is not being narrowed down, so that it looks in the current filter chain for a filter that is similar to the current filter and switch to it immediately (instead of deleting the whole chain and starting a new one). This can be particularly useful when the user is deleting some characters at the end filter `QLineEdit` (ie. when the filter changes back from `"abcd"` to `"abc"`, since you should already have a filter in the chain with `"abc"`). But currently, this is not implemented as I want the answer to be as minimal and clear as possible.

Comment: Thanks, Mike. I'm awarding you the bounty since I think this is the correct approach to the solution. Hyat's solution removes most of the overhead too and is good for practical purposes, but it doesn't feel complete because it doesn't  remove the redundant calls to `filterAcceptsRows()`, it just optimizes them. I think using chained `QSortFilterProxyModel` is not a problem - it makes accessing an element N times slower, but this affects only the elements currently being shown, which are not very big number. Also I like the possibility of further reusing the chained models for backspaces.

Comment: Hm, that's weird. I tried with a plain `QSortFilterProxyModel` and it becomes faster as it gets narrower. Not only that, but deleting chars is also fast, so they must use a similar filter chaining with "undo" functionality. That was unexpected. I think now the problem happens only when we override `filterAcceptsRows()` for a custom filter, and we then use `invalidateFilter()`. I made a test project at https://github.com/sashoalm/NarrowableFilterProxyModel.

Comment: Actually I was wrong, it doesn't do chaining, the speedup was entirely unrelated, sorry.

Comment: @sashoalm , nevermind. why did the speedup you noticed happen then?

Comment: I believe that it was because less items were filling the listbox. It was the listbox itself being filled that was slow, not the act of filtering. If you paste a more specific filter like `1111` it will be just as fast.

Comment: I took the idea from your class and reworked it a little bit in https://github.com/sashoalm/NarrowableFilterProxyModel. I made a new class called `AbstractProxyChainModel` that manages a stack of proxy models. It abstracts away the "narrowness" completely, inheriting classes must override a pure virtual function that compares 2 models and says whether they are identical, one is narrower or they are just different. I intend to use that in the future to create a multiple-column filter that also has chaining. Thanks for the answer again.

Answer (score 2):

Because the filters can also be generic (for custom filter sorting you are encouraged to override `filterAcceptsRow()`) the ProxyModel cannot know whether it will become narrower or not.

if you would need to provide it to the proxy as a parameter it would break encapsulation because the filter-logic should only be contained inside the filter model.

You cannot override `invalidateFilter` though because it is not declared virtual. What you can do is having a structure in your derived proxy where you store the values you lastly filtered in there and only check them in , when the filter just got narrower. Both of this you can do in `filterAcceptsRow()`.

`invalidateFilter()` still will call `rowCount()` though. So this function needs to have a low call time in your model for this to be effective.

Here is some pseudocode how `filterAcceptsRow()` could look like:

```
index // some index to refer to the element;

if(!selectionNarrowed()) //need search all elements
{
    m_filteredElements.clear(); //remove all previously filtered
    if(filterApplies(getFromSource(index))) //get element from sourceModel
    {
        m_filteredElements.add(index); //if applies add to "cache"
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

//selection has only narrowed down    
if(!filterApplies(m_filteredElements(index)) //is in "cache"?
{
    m_filteredElements.remove(index); //if not anymore: remove from cache
    return false;
}
return true;
```

There are some things to be aware of though. Be careful if you want to store the `QModelIndex`..You can have a look at [QPersistentModelIndex](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpersistentmodelindex.html).

You also need to be aware about changes in the underlying model and connect the appropriate slots and invalidate your "cache" in those cases.

While an alternative could be "filter stacking". I see this may get confusing when you really need to invalidate all filters.

Comment: Hm, if all this is in the code of `filterAcceptsRow`, how could it possibly have an effect to the quadratic time complexity in the qt base class that iterates from `0` to row count?

Comment: the iteration in the base class is just over the indexdes and input them to `filterAcceptsRow` so yeah these iterations are still there. But you don't check any string comparisons anymore for **all**lthe elements in the modell but only on a subset. Depending on how you setup your `selectionNarrowed()` and the `filteredElements` this can be faster than checking each string if it still matches the filter. So you can get a performance improvement without having to patch the Qt source code and getting into problems with their free license.